# Library of helpful responses

Tags: discussion, moderation, comment

Some situations come up frequently enough, especially with new users, that it seems useful to maintain a library of *polite*, *helpful* responses we can offer.  Mods (and anyone else) can then copy and paste from this library.

The purpose of this thread is to implement that library.

The intended structure is that each reply should offer one or more possible comments to respond to one defined situation.  (Thus, please feel free to edit an existing reply rather than create multiple replies for the same situation.)  Examples of such situations--which I have gleaned from recent moderator interventions--would include

- Incomprehensible or vague/ambiguous questions.
- Demands for homework solutions.
- Off-topic questions.
- Self-serving replies or overt marketing in replies.

I am also hopeful that by making this library available here, the community can gradually improve these stock messages via direct edits or comments.  Possibly we could even add amplifications in the replies (such as more extended discussions of what actions are expected in response) and link to them directly where appropriate.

Comment: see also: http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments

Comment: @Jeff Great!  That's an excellent vehicle for implementing this functionality (pre-loaded with some useful comments, too).  Because it's a personal modification--not shared across users--the replies here can still serve as a repository of text and means to exchange helpful moderation comments.

Comment: Good idea. I always hate trying to think how I should "sugar coat" my comments.

Comment: Re: @Jeff's suggestion above.  I installed that GreaseMonkey app and used it for a while: it's fun and works well.  However, it mysteriously vanished (FireFox 3.6.17, Win 7/64).  Therefore I don't want to rely on it.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140841/macro-for-comments and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments

Answer (score 9):

## Questions should be separated

> You are asking several questions here.
> Although they are clearly related, it
> would be better to address them in
> separate threads (with
> cross-references if needed), for it
> would be easier to focus on one issue
> at a time.

Answer (score 8):

## Homework Questions

> Please read the info for the "Homework" tag and restate your question accordingly. After editing it, you can re-open it.

Answer (score 8):

## Off-topic Questions

> We're leaving this thread open for a short while in the hope that you have a way to clarify it that is of statistical interest. If your interest is primarily in [**fill in this blank**] we'll migrate it to the [**blank**] site for you. If you don't do anything, we will need to  close it as off-topic.

Answer (score 8):

## Incomplete information

### Question concerning data analysis.

> This question looks interesting, but
> it is difficult to get an idea of the
> exact structure of your data. Without
> knowing [**blank**], it will be hard to
> provide a definitive answer. Could you
> provide additional information (e.g.,
> [**blank**])?

### Theoretical question.

> This topic might belong here but it is not yet possible to determine exactly what question is being asked.  Please clarify it and consider posting it on a site where it might be more relevant.

Comment: Feel free to propose a better heading for that particular situation.

Answer (score 8):

## Editing issues

> This site supports Markdown syntax for
> editing, and also $\LaTeX$ for
> mathematical expressions. Further
> information can be found here:
> https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help.  $\LaTeX$ help can be found at
> [LaTeX/Mathematics from the Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics),   [Getting Started with TeX, LaTeX, and Friends](http://www.tug.org/begin.html),
> [Michael Doob's "Gentle Introduction"](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/gentle/gentle.pdf), and [the Harvard Math Dept's "Introduction"](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/).

Comment: We need a link for LaTeX. I can only think of this one at the moment: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-typographic-support-is-available-to-support-display-of-statistical-formula.

Answer (score 5):

## Inappropriate Replies

> This is a fine reply but [**blank**] does not belong in it.  I do not want to presume too much by editing your reply myself, so I have provisionally closed it in the hope you will re-post it after making the necessary changes in the way you see fit.