# What's the deal with the new about page?

Tags: discussion

What's the story with the new [about page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/about)?  It's fancy now.  I like it, and I suspect it'll be more useful for new CV users this way.  *(Side question:  Should we link to it from the FAQ?)*

I will say that I wish the old info were still accessible somewhere, as I thought that information was useful enough that I discussed it [on](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24827/where-is-the-shared-variance-between-all-ivs-in-a-linear-multiple-regression-equ/24833#24833) [several](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1122/how-to-stem-the-tide-of-duplicate-qs/1137#1137) [occasions](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/how-should-questions-be-answered-on-cross-validated/1391#1391).

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to our attention.  But what specifically is your question?

Comment: I'm mostly wondering what the story is. Based on your response, I'm guessing you didn't know about this, & the SE team just decided to improve the about page. As side questions, I wonder if there should be links b/t about & FAQ, b/c both will have useful info for newcomers. I'm also wondering if the old info still exists anywhere, or can be appended, just b/c I thought it was insightful about the nature of CV (albeit probably less useful for most users).

Comment: It's a system-wide change to all the "About" pages AFAIK.  I agree that links can help.  Mods can create links by modifying the first section of the [faq].  We can't do anything directly to change the "About" page.

Comment: Mods can also alter the "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" section, @whuber.

Comment: @Aarthi I see the "edit" controls now: thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Another relevant post on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164778/what-should-we-put-on-our-about-page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163254/were-rolling-out-a-new-quick-start-guide-to-help-new-users-learn-the-basics):

> We've been working hard on ways to help improve the experience of new users, and one of the best ways to do that is to help teach them the basics about how our sites work before they run afoul of them.
>
> This will improve their odds of having a good first experience, speed up how quickly they can become contributing members of community, and head off the frustrations they sometimes have as a result of crashing into one of the many things that make us... different.

There's more commentary and information in the link, but that's the gist of it -- we changed it because the old version wasn't helping new users. I firmly believe the new version *does*.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Could you guys also add a link at the end to the FAQ? I saw your comment that the mods could do it to the "Get answers... " section, but that doesn't seem like the ideal place. Also, does the old info still exist anywhere? I suspect it may not have been very helpful for most people, but I did think it was insightful.

Comment: @gung That's a conversation your community will need to have. :)

Comment: @gung Apparently, we can also edit the foreword ("Cross Validated is a question and answer site (...)"). An alternative place would be the "Browse new questions, or ask your own" section, but this is beyond our mod privileges.

Comment: @chl, I would imagine the forward makes more sense as a place to have a brief note about the FAQ w/ a link.

Comment: @gung Done (though a bit late, sorry)!