# A proposal to better serve new users

Tags: feature-request

Cross Validated gets a lot of new users; perhaps other SE sites do as well, but I am not very familiar with them.

These new users often do not do things the "CV" or "SE" way, through no fault of their own.

I therefore propose that when a new user asks a question (or gives an answer or makes a comment) he or she be automatically be sent a copy of the FAQ or, at least, be directed to the FAQ.

Comment: +1 I think this is a great idea: at the very least, it will pre-empt a lot of comments we post asking new people to look at the FAQ. Any thing we can automate in order to help people write good questions deserves serious consideration.

Comment: +1, I agree that this is a great idea. However, I suspect it's out of our hands. I suspect the developers have to decide to do this & you may need to raise the idea on meta.SO.

Comment: I can raise it there, too @gung. But do they read the meta on the individual sites?

Comment: I think there are some people designated to lurk in the background on all the site-specific metas. But this would require major changes in the code underlying the site, & if done, would probably be done for all sites together. At least, that's my hunch.

Comment: (cc @whuber, @gung) I think some of this type of functionality has been added since we all joined. For example, if you try to answer a question when you're logged out, a little pop-up occurs that gives you a few tips for answering along with a link to [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Similar tips come up when you try to ask questions, with some links for help with asking questions. So, it seems that the SE network has already made some strides in this direction. Are you proposing something more?

Comment: @macro I have noticed that for comments. But I am proposing a link to the full FAQ, and only for first timers. And I just got one when I tried to cc whuber and gung...How did you do that?

Comment: I'm not sure how I did the double cc :-) Anyway, I was just thinking that whatever comes up when you're logged out is probably the same info that comes up when you're a new user. It seems the most crucial information to convey to new users is how to ask/answer but other info could also be useful.

Comment: Peter, I believe that this was possible because @whuber is a moderator. See this [Meta SO thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/150510) for more information. (/cc @Macro)

Answer (score 7):

On tex.SE, moderators and other users often leave a [welcome message](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3503) to all newcomers; it usually includes a link to their FAQ, as well as specific details regarding the question itself (e.g., [adding a minimal reproducible example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121155/how-to-adjust-a-table-to-fit-on-page#comment270513_121155)).

I like this idea, and maybe we could add some greeting message to our [Library of helpful responses](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/771/930)? I'm not sure we need to create a dedicated thread on Meta for that purpose, since most of the information is expected to  be available in our FAQ.

Comment: Also a great idea.  It would be nice to see this *automated,* though, rather than relying on the community to notice every new member. We are now getting around 50 questions per day and most of them from new people, plus answers from new people. Those numbers will surely grow and when they do, our ability to serve these people quickly and consistently will diminish.

Comment: @whuber Agree. Post notices (like we have for answers) would be great. Different comments could be added automatically by the system, depending on content length, other SE activity (i.e., no other SE accounts means this is a totally new user on the network), etc.